# SqlGeography in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm researching how to load a .shp file into Geography columns in SQL 2008.

I'm reading this blog:
http://consultingblogs.emc.com/stevewright/archive/2009/01/23/how-to-load-spatial-data-into-sql-server-2008-from-net.aspx and it states:

> To use the SqlGeography C# type you need to add reference to the following name space: Microsoft.SqlServer.Types. This can be found in the following dll: Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll

However, I don't see that anywhere on my machine.  I was looking in the Add Reference under the .Net tab and the COM tab and I don't see it.  I searched for `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` on my machine as well and did not find it.

Is there something I need to install on my machine to be able to use SqlGeography in C#?

**UPDATE!**

After finishing reading the blog entry I found this:

> Like the report viewer control the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types namespace
> is not installed with .Net. For the application to work on another
> computer, without having to install SQL server or their client tools,
> a Redistributable package would need to be installed.
>
> The SQL Server
> System CLR Types package contains the components implementing the new
> geometry, geography, and hierarchyid types in SQL Server 2008. This
> component can be installed separately from the server to allow client
> applications to use these types outside of the server.   A version can
> be found here:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en

However, the link is no longer valid....  So does anyone know where I can get this .dll?

**UPDATE w/Answer!**

I wound up doing a search online and found that the dll exists here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
> Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll

Once I added that reference I no longer saw the error and I'm able to use the SqlGeography as a type in C#.

Comment: I know this question is old, but since you have an answer, why not post it, mark it, and then users like me won't think the question is still unresolved! :)

Comment: any good reference about load shp files to sql server? can you share it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wound up doing a search online and found that the dll exists here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll`

Once I added that reference I no longer saw the error and I'm able to use the SqlGeography as a type in C#.

Answer (score 5):

These exist as a nuget package now

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/

so it is better to use that rather than a direct ref to the DLL.

Comment: Yes this is a much better option and be careful what version of the package you install -- choose 10.50.1600.1 for compatibility with SQL 2008, for example -- or you will get weird casting errors due to version conflicts.